# Handling the SYSDATE in Delete statement | Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

Currently, the below code deletes the backdated data from my table starting from 12-APR-2019

```
DELETE FROM XYZ WHERE check_date < ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -24);
```

How can I modify the code so that the table will store data for the whole April month i.e. table needs to have values starting from 01-APR-2019 and delete the previous dates data (from 31-MAR-2019 and backwards)

Thank You!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Those date/time functions are product specific.)

Comment: Hi, @jarlh this query is for Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I modify the code so that the table will store data for the whole April month i.e. table needs to have values starting from 01-APR-2019 and delete the previous dates data (from 31-MAR-2019 and backwards)

```
delete from xyz where check_date < date '2019-04-01'
```

is the most obvious solution.

---

If you have to use `sysdate`, maybe you wanted to **trucate** it to month:

```
DELETE FROM XYZ WHERE check_date < ADD_MONTHS (trunc(SYSDATE, 'mm'), -24);
```

because of

```
SQL> select add_months(sysdate, -24) your_result,
  2         add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -24) my_result
  3  from dual;

YOUR_RESULT         MY_RESULT
------------------- -------------------
12.04.2019 10:14:30 01.04.2019 00:00:00

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
trunc( sysdate, 'MM' )
```

returns midnight on the first of the current month.  So

```
add_months( trunc( sysdate, 'MM' ), -24 )
```

would return April 1, 2019 if run today (April 12, 2021).  So you'd just need

```
DELETE FROM XYZ 
 WHERE check_date < add_months( trunc( sysdate, 'MM' ), -24 )
```